# Copy command can't find the file on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, cmd.exe

Although I can see the file in windows explorer, I can see it when I run 'dir' command on that folder, but when I run copy command to copy this file to another location, it says "The system can't find the file specified."

I believe this is something related to security and permissions but even given fullcontrol to everyone doesn't work.

Need some help.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be seperate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use XCOPY command instead of COPY . It is more reliable command than copy.

Comment: It was a hidden file which can't be copied using copy command. Had to use xcopy with /h switch. Worked fine. Pls update your answer for hidden files and I'll mark it as answer then.